# how to specify a letter at given position in a string

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Is there a build-in function in solidity allows to specify a letter in a string at given position like a = string b[i], where i indicates the position of that letter?

Answer (score 9):

Strings aren't currently index-accessible.

From the Solidity [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html?highlight=string):

> Variables of type bytes and string are special arrays. A bytes is
>   similar to byte[], but it is packed tightly in calldata. **string is
>   equal to bytes but does not allow length or index access** (for now).

So use `bytes` instead, though note:

> If you want to access the byte-representation of a string s, use
>   bytes(s).length / bytes(s)[7] = ‘x’;. Keep in mind that you are
>   accessing the low-level bytes of the utf-8 representation, and not the
>   individual characters!

Comment: is there any update on the matter by now?