# How to do CharAt in solidity

Tags: solidity

How can I do a charAt() in solidity? Solidity has little support for strings because it is expensive. That matters to the main network, but I am running a personal network so the gas cost can be whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Letter at given position in a string](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3770/how-to-specify-a-letter-at-given-position-in-a-string), based on [Types in solidity](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html?highlight=string)

> Strings aren't currently index-accessible.
>
> From the Solidity docs:

`Variables of type bytes and string are special arrays. A bytes is similar to byte[], but it is packed tightly in calldata. string is equal to bytes but does not allow length or index access (for now).`

> So use bytes instead, though note:

`If you want to access the byte-representation of a string s, use bytes(s).length / bytes(s)[7] = ‘x’;. Keep in mind that you are accessing the low-level bytes of the utf-8 representation, and not the individual characters!`